# Esri draw toolbar equivalent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tools, toolbar

The company I work for is moving from ArcMap to QGIS, so we are trying to find QGIS equivalent tools and one being Esri's draw toolbar. The main of the toolbar I am looking for is the circle drawing function, Without creating a layer i am currently able to select the circle drawing tool click on a point and press shift + r to draw a circle with a set radius.

We use this **a lot** so having a QGIS equivalent is pretty important. So far I've tried using buffers, but that requires temp layers to be made, a UI to be opened and information added and styling to be changed so you can see what's underneath. I've also tried making a permanent polygon "annotation layer" if you will and using the add circle by center point and another point tool combined with the advanced digitizing tool so draw a circle with a set radius, but that is also very cumbersome and kind of slow to do and requires either a permanent layer in the project, layer dragged in each time you want to use it or a temp layer made each time you want to use it.

TL;DR Is there something similar to the Esri draw toolbar ?

Comment: QDraw Plugin has Circle +Radius without the need to edit a layer https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qdraw/

Comment: [QAD](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) is also another option. You can draw a circle with a defined radius.